# Использование функции как объекта

Tags: javascript

Читаю учебник по JavaScript. Сказано: "Функция в JavaScript является объектом, поэтому можно присваивать свойства прямо к ней, вот так:"

```
function f() {}

f.test = 5;
alert( f.test );
```

Я понимаю, что тут происходит. Но, как мне кажется, это достаточно странный код.

Есть ли ситуации, где оправдано использование функции как объекта подобным образом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой пример, библиотека `jquery`. Вы можете использовать глобальный объект `jQuery` как функцию, и как контейнер вспомогательных методов:

```
jQuery('body').css('background-color', 'red'); // используем как функцию
if (jQuery.isFunction(null)) { /* ... */ } // используем как объект
```